# Debugging and updating values in APEX Interactive report

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have two problems in my Interactive Report APEX 4.2.5 application.  I have seen several examples of this functionality but they have not help me so far..

1 - In the report SELECT statement I am selecting some of the fields using apex_item.text, as I want user to be able to updated these fields.  This part is working fine.  My problem is with writing the updated values back to a table (the SELECT is on a view).  I have a SQL Autonomous block process that is supposed to be doing this (looping through the rows and accessing values using APEX_APPLICATION.G_Fxx) but it is not working.  No errors are returned after Submit, instead the values revert to original values.  How can I get these updates to save in the table?

2 - Within the SQL process I have enabled and added some APEX_DEBUG.MESSAGE statements, but I do not see the result of these statements anywhere in the debug log or table.  How can I see the result of these debug commands?

Here is the SELECT:

```
select REQUISITION_LINE_ID
,apex_item.hidden(50,REQUISITION_LINE_ID,10,10) rid
,REQ_NUMBER
,REQ_LINE_NUMBER
,REQUISITION_QUANTITY
,SO_NUMBER
,SO_LINE
,ORDERED_QUANTITY
,SKU
,DESCRIPTION
,apex_item.text(10, SUPPLY_PO_NUMBER, 10, 10) SUPPLY_PO_NUMBER
,apex_item.text(20, SUPPLY_PO_LINE, 10, 10) SUPPLY_PO_LINE
,apex_item.text(30, SUPPLY_PO_SHIPMENT , 10, 10) SUPPLY_PO_SHIPMENT 
from camlb.xxcb_requisition_reference;
```

And here is the SQL process:

```
declare
id number;
poorder number;
poline number;
poshipment number;

begin
APEX_DEBUG.ENABLE(p_level => 9);

for i in 1..APEX_APPLICATION.G_F50.count 
loop

id := APEX_APPLICATION.G_F50(i);
poorder:=APEX_APPLICATION.G_F10(i);
poline:=APEX_APPLICATION.G_F20(i);
poshipment:=APEX_APPLICATION.G_F30(i);

APEX_DEBUG_MESSAGE.LOG_MESSAGE('ID is ' || id || ', PO is ' || poorder || ', SUPPLY_PO_LINE is '|| poline || ', SUPPLY_PO_SHIPMENT is ' || poshipment);
APEX_DEBUG.MESSAGE('ID is ' || id || ', PO is ' || poorder || ', SUPPLY_PO_LINE is '|| poline || ', SUPPLY_PO_SHIPMENT is ' || poshipment);

update APPS.po_requisition_lines_all 
set ATTRIBUTE1=poorder,
ATTRIBUTE2=poline,
ATTRIBUTE3=poshipment
where requisition_line_id=id;

end loop;
end;
```

Answer (score -1):

Note, the checkbox array will be dense, while your text box arrays are sparse, thanks to HTML behaviour. There are a few posts out there on this topic, plus some other general checkbox processing posts https://www.talkapex.com/2009/01/apex-report-with-checkboxes-advanced/

You need to put your application in debug mode, using the developer toolbar usually found at the bottom of your runtime page (if you're also logged into the builder).

This will set the relevant URL parameter to YES. Look for the log related to the page submit, not render. It might also pay to log the relevant array counts before entering the loop.

Comment: I am trying to write to debug log using APEX_DEBUG.MESSAGE but the messages do not show up.  I click on Debug, perform action, and then View Debug.  The APEX_DEBUG.MESSAGEs do not show in the log.

Comment: Are you sure you're opening the correct debug log listing? For processing, I think it will say "accept" with the name of the button as suffix, versus "show" which is just rendering the page

Comment: Yes.  SHOW gives logging for the SELECT that renders the page.  ACCEPT gives the logging for what happens after the Submit/Save button is clicked.  But alas, no APEX_DEBUG.MESSAGEs are displayed. I wonder if it needs to be enabled somewhere in APEX admin in addition to enabling in individual objects via APEX_DEBUG.ENABLE.  But I have not found any documentation related to this.

Comment: Not sure how I missed it before, but I found where you can enable debugging in 'Edit Application Properties' [link](https://docs.oracle.com/html/E39147_04/debug_mode.htm).  However I have set it to Yes, but still no debug messages.